# Marketing Cloud Cordova Plugin fails to install

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I had this plugin working and was able to successfully install it around two months ago, now I see the following error when I try to install it.

Failed to restore plugin "com.salesforce.marketingcloud.cordovaplugin" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Failed to fetch plugin com.salesforce.marketingcloud.cordovaplugin@https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin.git#1.0.2 via registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serge, also make sure you note our docs about --nofetch. "3. Use this command to install the plugin in your Cordova project." github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I don't know what has changed but I had to add --nofetch flag when I was running Cordova  add plugin

eg.

cordova plugin add https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin.git#1.0.2 --save --nofetch (obviously I took out my config settings)

or cordova plugin add /MC-Cordova-Plugin-1.0.2/ --save --nofetch

got the idea from here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43856285/failed-to-get-absolute-path-to-installed-module

Comment: Fetch uses your system npm to npm install modules into your project. I wonder if there are some settings in the mobile-push npm plugin that do not match changes elsewhere in the project. See:
https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/05/04/cordova-7.html for the change in Fetch default functionality. Is this possibly related to the issue you are seeing?

Comment: Serge, also make sure you note our docs about --nofetch. 

"3. Use this command to install the plugin in your Cordova project." https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin

Comment: Hi Tom. Thank you for pointing this out, I 've missed that part. Can you post it as an answer rather than reply so I can accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Sure thing! Glad I could help.